# How to tag taken seats in Cinema. C Programming

Tags: c, console

First I want to say that I am a beginner in C and in programming at all. 
C is my first language and I find it very interesting.
I am writing a program that will simulate a cinema software. I mean you choose movie, time and you choose seats.
I am done with selecting the movie and time but I have a problem with the seats.
The thing I am trying to do is when you select Row and Column, somehow to print out in the console which seat is taken (changing the color, increasing the font or something like that)

Here is my code:

```
 void SeatSelection()
{
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int i, j;
    printf("\t\t\t\tSCREEN\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    int A[11][11] = {
        { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 11; j++)
            printf("%d\t", A[i][j]);

        printf("\n\n");
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Choose seat: Row and Column\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
        if ((row<1 || row>10) && (column<1 || column>10)) printf("Wrong choice, try again\n");
    } while ((row<1 || row>10) && (column<1 || column>10));
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a second table `taken[][]`. For a seat `(row, column)` taken[row][column] is 1 if the seat is taken, else it is 0. Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void SeatSelection()
{
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int i, j;
    int A[11][11] = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }
    };

    int taken[11][11] = {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    printf("============= The Cinema ==============\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            printf(" %d  ", A[i][j]);

        printf("\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    do
    {
        printf("Choose seat: Row and Column\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%d %d", &row, &column);
        if ((row<1 || row>10) && (column<1 || column>10)) printf("Wrong choice, try again\n");
        if(taken[row][column]) printf("This seat is taken, try again\n");
        else {
          taken[row][column] = 1;
          printf("======== The Cinema =========\n");
          for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
          {
              for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
                  if(taken[i][j] == 0)
                    printf(" %d  ", A[i][j]);
                  else
                    printf("[%d] ", A[i][j]);
              }
              printf("\n");
          }
        }
        fflush(stdout);
    } while (true);
}

int main() {
  SeatSelection();
  return 0;
}
```

### Edit

I have made some alterations to your code, but i think you get the idea :) If you don't understand something just tell me...

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind, thank you a lot !!!

Edit: I don't understand why did you change the first column and row to 0?

Comment: @user3476022 I was a bit confused about the usage of the first row, and the lack of initialisation of the last column. From those two, the second is more important, as the compiler puts in uninitialised positions random integers which may cause peculiar runtime errors...